# Map Java Code to SOAP & REST

Tags: java, rest, soap, jersey

I'm developing an application that connects to two servers, one using REST and the other using SOAP. So the input I give needs to be mapped into XML format understood by the server API's. I saw somewhere that Jersey can only be used to map REST. If so, I need a way to map java code to SOAP.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://aruld.info/soap-over-resty-client/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) is one of many JAX-RS implementations. In other words, it is a framework for implementing restful services in Java. Other such frameworks are [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) and [RestEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org) .

Similarly, there is a Java API for SOAP web services known as JAX-WS. It too has many implementations like [Apache Axis2](https://axis.apache.org/) and [JBossWS](http://jbossws.jboss.org/).

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) is one such framework that implements both JAX-RS and JAX-WS.

Hope this clarifies.